# it is possible to show the top menu item as active when a corresponding sub menu item is active?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

i have following menu structure and using the standard menu joomla module:

```
menu top items: home, techniques 

menu main items: home, about

menu techniques items: tech1, tech2, ...
```

e.g. when i click the home top menu item, the home top menu item and the home sub menu item are shown as active. i want to have the same behaviour for the other menu times. for instance, when the sub item tech1 is clicked, tech1 and techniques should be marked as active. can i reach my goal with the standard joomla modules or is it better to use another extension?

for a demo visit this website: http://www.karl-poecher.at

i'm using joomla 1.6

e.g., when cklicking 'Segmentmassage' the top menu item 'Technicken' should be active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it appears where you want to highlight is in the breadcrumb component. Short answer is no, but you could instead make the menu techniques items sub items of your main menu and then restructure how the output looks with CSS accordingly.